# Variable margins / padding / spacer that can disappear entirely?

Tags: css, margin, padding, space

I am looking for variable margins / spacers / padding

if possible obviously a clean CSS solution

[see the problem in the codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbQBKX)

In words:

Today we have many different devices with different resolutions. Let's say our designer designs a webpage for a device that has at least 900 pixels height. With a top margin of 150 pixels and a bottom margin of 100 pixels.
Now guess what happens when someone comes with a 700 pixels high screen. A scrollbar appears, but in reality, we could just make disappear the top and bottom margin a bit, right? Since they have 250 pixels height, we can just take off 120 pixels top margin (leaving 30) and 80 pixels bottom margin (leaving 20). So keeping the margin ratio nicely, and keeping the page full screen.

is there something in CSS i am overlooking?

HTML

```
  <div class="container2">x
  <div class="container">
  <div class="d1"> Make top and bottom margin be variable </div>
  <div class="d2"> but top margin 1.5 as big as bottom margin </div><div class="d2"> . </div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Variable means: make sure 
      </td>
      <td>That if there is not enough space (decrease html and body size)
      </td>
      <td>That the margins can disappear entirely (does not need to be margin, but a spacer right)
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
    <div class="d3">x </div>

</div>


</div>
```

CSS

```
   /*silly attempt:*/
.container{
  xpadding-top: 1.5%;
  xpadding-bottom: 1%;
}
/*silly attempt end*/

.container{
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.container2{
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

.d1{
    margin-top: 150px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.d2{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}

table tr td{
  background-color: beige;
}

.d3{
  background-color: brown;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

* {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using CSS media queries?

Comment: @ChrisSpittles oh I am certainly using media queries. But I am using it for the most important resolutions. Everything in between should kinda fit in by itself. By solving this problem for example, and providing an actual min-height you solve all problems for all devices in one go

Comment: @ChrisSpittles to make it more clear: the use case is that the designer wants to provide full screen background-images. and fit everything into full screens. You go from one full screen to the next. This should follow this rule, only break if the full screen does not have enough height to fit the content that it contains

Comment: would flex be an hint ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwJody

Comment: You should set your margins in vh units (for example, 100px on a 900px screen becomes 11.1vh, which will shrink to 80px on a 700px screen.